# React component cant recognize prop

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

So i am trying to pass an array of objects from the main App.js file to another smaller component through props but for some reason inside the smaller component file it fails to recognize the prop

[image: smaller_component]

[image: error]

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't recognize because of the way you're using the bracket. The syntax that you're using supposed to be JS injected into JSX so you'd need to wrap your `props.items` inside a JSX. Without it, JS will interpret it as if you're trying to initialize an object with key `prop` and throw an error that a comma is expected instead of a period. If you just want call `prop.items` like what you're trying to achieve, there's no need to wrap it inside the bracket and parenthesis at all and you just need to call `return prop.items.map(...)`